# Scraping Data from 1 Table on Website in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, export-to-excel

I am very new to coding in **R** so was hoping for some help! Trying to do some lake population management analysis via the Minnesota DNR website. I have tried ReadHTLMLtable and HTMLparse but that only seems to work if I am looking for one specific table.  If I am looking for the same table on a number of different pages (ie. different lakes), then it gets messed up.

Here is what I am looking to do:

1. Build a code in **R** to scrape 1 table from the Minnesota DNR for a large variety of lakes 
   (see example at link: http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/lakefind/showreport.html?downum=56011602)
2. The table I am interested in is called "**Length of Select Species Sampled - All Gear Combined** "
3. Perform this data scraping on a number of different lakes and export the data to Excel

Any pointers would be awesome! If possible, automating it to do all lakes within a county would be ideal but this is a start!

Comment: What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to Stackoverflow. I understand you are new to R but you can ask for direct answers here without showing what you have already tried. This question will be marked as closed for being too broad.

Comment: Sorry- i did not know that was a rule! I have tried a couple of the different packages within R.  For example, HTMLParse and ReadHTMLtable.  Both work if there is only one table you are looking for.  If you are looking for the same table for a variety of different lakes for example, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, even if you had tried standard `rvest` calls, it would not have worked thank to the javascript call it makes to get the table data.

Either use RSelenium, [`splashr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) or the following (which calls the same API the web page does):

```
library(httr)

res <- GET("http://maps2.dnr.state.mn.us/cgi-bin/lakefinder/detail.cgi",
         query=list(type="lake_survey",
                    id="56011602",
                    `_`=as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000))


str(content(res, as="parsed", simplifyVector=TRUE))
## List of 4
##  $ timestamp: int 1488159503
##  $ status   : chr "SUCCESS"
##  $ result   :List of 13
##   ..$ averageWaterClarity: chr "5.0"
##   ..$ sampledPlants      : list()
##   ..$ officeCode         : chr "F115"
##   ..$ littoralAcres      : int 113
##   ..$ shoreLengthMiles   : num 4.26
##   ..$ areaAcres          : num 423
##   ..$ surveys            :'data.frame':  6 obs. of  8 variables:
##   .. ..$ fishCatchSummaries:List of 6
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   22 obs. of  9 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileCount : chr [1:22] "0.4-1.3" "2.5-16.5" "0.3-1.2" "1.2-6.3" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ CPUE          : chr [1:22] "0.80" "0.75" "0.20" "1.00" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalCatch    : int [1:22] 4 3 1 4 20 32 12 86 4 1 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ species       : chr [1:22] "BOF" "BLC" "WAE" "WAE" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalWeight   : num [1:22] 25.4 1.4 1.3 3.4 49 29 11.1 5.4 2.1 0.1 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileWeight: chr [1:22] "2.3-4.1" "0.1-0.3" "0.8-2.8" "1.2-2.7" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ averageWeight : chr [1:22] "6.35" "0.47" "1.30" "0.85" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gearCount     : int [1:22] 5 4 5 4 4 5 4 5 5 4 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gear          : chr [1:22] "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" ...
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   23 obs. of  9 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileCount : chr [1:23] "2.5-16.5" "N/A" "0.3-1.2" "0.2-0.8" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ CPUE          : chr [1:23] "0.20" "0.43" "0.57" "0.20" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalCatch    : int [1:23] 1 3 4 1 16 52 27 16 20 5 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ species       : chr [1:23] "BLC" "NOP" "WAE" "BOF" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalWeight   : num [1:23] 0.1 10.6 6.5 8 22.9 82.6 27 14.2 2.9 4.9 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileWeight: chr [1:23] "0.1-0.3" "N/A" "0.8-2.8" "2.4-4.2" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ averageWeight : chr [1:23] "0.10" "3.53" "1.62" "8.00" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gearCount     : int [1:23] 5 7 7 5 5 5 7 5 7 7 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gear          : chr [1:23] "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" ...
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   24 obs. of  9 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileCount : chr [1:24] "2.5-16.5" "N/A" "0.3-1.2" "0.9-5.7" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ CPUE          : chr [1:24] "0.40" "0.67" "0.17" "16.67" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalCatch    : int [1:24] 2 4 1 100 17 8 27 11 200 5 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ species       : chr [1:24] "BLC" "NOP" "WAE" "YEB" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalWeight   : num [1:24] 2.25 9.5 2 68 26.91 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileWeight: chr [1:24] "0.1-0.3" "N/A" "0.8-2.8" "0.5-0.8" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ averageWeight : chr [1:24] "1.12" "2.38" "2.00" "0.68" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gearCount     : int [1:24] 5 6 6 6 5 5 5 6 6 5 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gear          : chr [1:24] "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard trap nets" ...
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   28 obs. of  9 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileCount : chr [1:28] "0.4-1.3" "2.5-16.5" "0.3-1.2" "0.2-0.8" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ CPUE          : chr [1:28] "0.33" "0.56" "0.56" "0.44" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalCatch    : int [1:28] 3 5 5 4 6 69 27 12 10 62 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ species       : chr [1:28] "BOF" "BLC" "WAE" "BOF" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalWeight   : int [1:28] 5380 1356 2320 11350 3446 48119 19484 4984 3084 3150 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileWeight: chr [1:28] "2.3-4.1" "0.1-0.3" "0.8-2.8" "2.4-4.2" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ averageWeight : chr [1:28] "3.95" "0.60" "1.02" "6.26" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gearCount     : int [1:28] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gear          : chr [1:28] "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" ...
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   28 obs. of  9 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileCount : chr [1:28] "0.4-1.3" "2.5-16.5" "0.3-1.2" "0.2-0.8" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ CPUE          : chr [1:28] "0.11" "3.44" "0.22" "0.22" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalCatch    : int [1:28] 1 31 2 2 4 35 8 6 23 9 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ species       : chr [1:28] "BOF" "BLC" "WAE" "BOF" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalWeight   : int [1:28] 1280 6859 1310 2300 1807 26553 6205 2279 10343 875 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileWeight: chr [1:28] "2.3-4.1" "0.1-0.3" "0.8-2.8" "2.4-4.2" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ averageWeight : chr [1:28] "2.82" "0.49" "1.44" "2.54" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gearCount     : int [1:28] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gear          : chr [1:28] "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" ...
##   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':   25 obs. of  9 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileCount : chr [1:25] "2.5-16.5" "0.3-1.2" "0.2-0.8" "N/A" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ CPUE          : chr [1:25] "3.00" "0.22" "0.11" "0.11" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalCatch    : int [1:25] 27 2 1 1 11 1 85 7 3 1 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ species       : chr [1:25] "BLC" "WAE" "BOF" "NOP" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ totalWeight   : int [1:25] 4743 3009 2200 934 13597 2350 58380 3128 1612 100 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ quartileWeight: chr [1:25] "0.1-0.3" "0.8-2.8" "2.4-4.2" "N/A" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ averageWeight : chr [1:25] "0.39" "3.32" "4.85" "2.06" ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gearCount     : int [1:25] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ gear          : chr [1:25] "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" "Standard gill nets" "Standard trap nets" ...
##   .. ..$ surveyDate        : chr [1:6] "1989-08-02" "1984-08-01" "1978-08-07" "1999-08-02" ...
##   .. ..$ surveySubType     : chr [1:6] "Population Assessment" "Population Assessment" "Re-Survey" "Population Assessment" ...
##   .. ..$ headerInfo        :List of 6
##   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "East Leaf" NA "56011602" "1989-08-02" ...
##   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "East Leaf" NA "56011602" "1984-08-01" ...
##   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "East Leaf" NA "56011602" "1978-08-07" ...
##   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "East Leaf" NA "56011602" "1999-08-02" ...
##   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "East Leaf" NA "56011602" "2004-08-02" ...
##   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "East Leaf" NA "56011602" "2010-08-02" ...
##   .. ..$ surveyType        : chr [1:6] "Standard Survey" "Standard Survey" "Standard Survey" "Standard Survey" ...
##   .. ..$ narrative         : chr [1:6] "<p>NOP ABUNDANCE HAS DECLINED FROM 10.4 PER GILL NET LIFT IN 1984 TO 5.0 DURING THIS SURVEY.  AVERAGE WEIGHT OF NOP WAS 2.5 POU"| __truncated__ "<p>NETTING DATA INDICATES THAT NORTHERN PIKE AND YELLOW PERCH NUMBERS ARE ABOVE THE AREA NET MEDIAN BLUEGILL, PUMPKINSEED, LARG"| __truncated__ "<p>TEST NET CATCHES OF YEP, BLBS AND YEBS WERE ABOVE AVERAGE.  WAES AND SUCKERS WERE CAUGHT IN NEAR AVERAGE NUMBERS AND TULLIBE"| __truncated__ "<p>East Leaf Lake is a 404 acre mesotrophic (moderately fertile) lake located in eastern Otter Tail County, approximately five "| __truncated__ ...
##   .. ..$ surveyID          : chr [1:6] "102083" "102084" "102085" "102592" ...
##   .. ..$ lengths           :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  18 variables:
##   .. .. ..$ LMB:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 2 4 14
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 11 2 5 6 1 1 2 3
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:11, 1:2] 10 11 12 13 15 4 5 6 7 8 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 14 15 1 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 11 15 15
##   .. .. ..$ YEP:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 3 4 4
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:5, 1:2] 3 5 6 7 8 2 109 153 50 4
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 4 5 6 7 1 83 55 5
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 4 5 6 7 2 180 67 4
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 8 7 7
##   .. .. ..$ BLG:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 3 3 3
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:7, 1:2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 27 27 33 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:7, 1:2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 17 9 24 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:7, 1:2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 6 1 5 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 9 9 9
##   .. .. ..$ NOP:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 11 11 13
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:14, 1:2] 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:10, 1:2] 11 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 30 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:12, 1:2] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 25 30 24
##   .. .. ..$ WAE:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 9 7 13
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:12, 1:2] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:9, 1:2] 11 15 16 17 19 20 21 7 9 1 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:10, 1:2] 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 24 25 26 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 24 21 26
##   .. .. ..$ TLC:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 11 NA 8
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:5, 1:2] 11 12 15 17 18 1 1 1 2 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 8 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 18 NA 8
##   .. .. ..$ BLB:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 6 12 6
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3, 1:2] 10 6 9 2 1 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 12 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3, 1:2] 13 15 6 1 1 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 10 12 15
##   .. .. ..$ PMK:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 3 3 6
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 3 4 5 6 15 20 16 19
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 3 5 6 7 1 2 6 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 6 2
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 6 7 6
##   .. .. ..$ RKB:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 3 5 5
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:6, 1:2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 3 2 1 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3, 1:2] 5 6 7 1 1 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 5 9 1 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 8 7 9
##   .. .. ..$ YEB:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 6 8 11
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:6, 1:2] 10 11 12 13 6 9 9 4 2 4 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:6, 1:2] 10 11 12 13 14 8 3 12 9 3 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3, 1:2] 11 12 13 4 5 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 13 14 13
##   .. .. ..$ WTS:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 8 10 8
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:12, 1:2] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:10, 1:2] 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:8, 1:2] 12 13 16 17 18 19 20 8 2 1 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 22 20 20
##   .. .. ..$ BOF:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 14 19 24
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:6, 1:2] 14 20 23 25 26 27 1 1 1 1 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3, 1:2] 19 20 21 1 1 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 24 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 27 21 24
##   .. .. ..$ BRB:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 8 10 13
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 10 11 14 8 3 1 1 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 10 11 12 13 3 9 2 3
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:2, 1:2] 13 14 4 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 14 13 14
##   .. .. ..$ CAP:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 14 23 NA
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 14 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 23 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 14 23 NA
##   .. .. ..$ SHR:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 10 11 NA
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 10 1
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:3, 1:2] 11 14 16 2 2 2
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 10 16 NA
##   .. .. ..$ BLC:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 4 5 4
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:4, 1:2] 10 4 8 9 2 1 1 10
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:7, 1:2] 10 11 12 5 6 8 9 7 4 1 ...
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1:9, 1:2] 10 11 12 4 5 6 7 8 9 90 ...
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA 10 12 12
##   .. .. ..$ HSF:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA NA NA 6
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 6 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA NA NA 6
##   .. .. ..$ GRR:'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
##   .. .. .. ..$ minimum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA NA NA 22
##   .. .. .. ..$ fishCount     :List of 6
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. .. .. .. ..$ : int [1, 1:2] 22 1
##   .. .. .. ..$ maximum_length: int [1:6] NA NA NA NA NA 22
##   ..$ accesses           :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  5 variables:
##   .. ..$ accessTypeId      : chr "CO"
##   .. ..$ location          : chr " "
##   .. ..$ publicUseAuthCode : chr "OPEN"
##   .. ..$ ownerTypeId       : chr "DNR"
##   .. ..$ lakeAccessComments: chr " "
##   ..$ lakeName           : chr "East Leaf"
##   ..$ DOWNumber          : chr "56011602"
##   ..$ waterClarity       : chr [1, 1:2] "08/02/2010" "5"
##   ..$ meanDepthFeet      : int 0
##   ..$ maxDepthFeet       : int 47
##  $ message  : chr "Normal execution."
```